# ArcObjects C#: How to add selected features to a Data Grid View

Tags: arcobjects, c#

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I'm trying to write a C# .NET add-in for ArcMap and I need some help. I want to be able to select a set of features in an SDE and then click a button that would add the selected features' field to a data grid view. I have been able to have selected features be added to a list box with a button but I can't modify the code to be a data grid. Below is my code so far after I've set up the SDE workspace.

```
        IEnumFeature pEnumFeat = (IEnumFeature)Pmap.FeatureSelection;
        IFields fields;
        pEnumFeat.Reset();
        IEnumFeatureSetup enumFeatSetup = (IEnumFeatureSetup)pEnumFeat;
        enumFeatSetup.AllFields = true;
        try
        {
            IFeature pfeat = pEnumFeat.Next();


            while (pfeat != null)
            {
                fields = pfeat.Fields;
                int x = fields.FindField("NAME OF FIELD");
                list.Add(pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString());
                Debug.Print(pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString());


                if (pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString() != "")
                    LstBxWellList.Items.Add(pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString());

                pfeat = pEnumFeat.Next();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to add a single "hello world" string to your datagridview?

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, or isn't detailed enough, maybe post some code you've tried for adding the data to the DataGridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think this is the simplest way to add each value in a loop, rather than binding the DataGridView to a list.  Your screenshot looks like you already have a column defined, if that's the case, ignore the first line:

```
myDataGridView.Columns.Add("Wellname", "Wellname");
while (pfeat != null)
{
    fields = pfeat.Fields;
    int x = fields.FindField("NAME OF FIELD");
    if (pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString() != "")
    {
         MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString());
    }
    pfeat = pEnumFeat.Next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Karl, the code allowed for a selected feature's field to be added to the data grid view. I didn't have to use myDataGridView.Columns.Add("Wellname", "Wellname"); becuse I had already added the column in the form design but everything else worked as intended.

Comment: I'm working more on this and I'm now trying to add multiple fields into a new already defined column. Would I just need to copy/paste this below and name a different field, different int value and some how tell it to add to the same row but column 1? As of now this only adds a new row for each field and not into the next column.

Comment: You can create an object array and pass that to the MyDataGridView.Rows.Add method. I think that this would work: MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] {pfeat.get_value(x).ToString(), secondColumnValue, thirdColumnValue});  Some other options to consider here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the Datasource for your DataGridView to your list. I would refresh afterwards, though I don't know if that's necessary or not:

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = list;
myDataGridView.Refresh();
```

Comment: I want to go in the direction of not having a list at all and just having the datagridview populated with a field of a selected feature. I'm fairly new to ArcObjects so I havent been able to write anything beyond the code for adding the selected feature to a list.

Comment: I'm assuming that in the line where you have: list.Add(pfeat.get_Value(x).ToString()); that "list" refers to a List<string> data structure. You could use that and bind it to the DataGridView as in this answer, but still skip the ListBox. But I'll post an alternative solution as another answer.